# Git ghost commit eludes log

Tags: git

Today I was working on one of my projects and I realized some weirdness with git. Git would allow you commit your work to a ghost branch. I use the term ***ghost branch*** because the changes exist somewhere in the tree but evades `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all`. Can anyone explain to me why this is?

#### Steps to reproduce this behaviour

Enter *detached head* state (you can get there by performing `git checkout <hash>`).

```
# Not currently on any branch.
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   uml 1.pdf
```

Make some changes to your codebase. And check the status of the working directory using `git status`. This should list the changes but state that you are not on any branch.

```
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .gitignore
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   uml 1.pdf
```

Commit the changes using `git commit -am '<message>'`

```
[detached HEAD ded7725] updated .gitignore
 1 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

If you then checkout a known branch, "master" for example, all changes commited in the detached head state is gone. This is expected.

Runnig `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` will show all commits *except* the one committed on the *detached head* (`ded7725` in my case).

However, a `git checkout <hash-for-ghost-branch>` returns the changes committed to the ghost branch. Problem is: one cannot remember this hash forever.

The expected behaviour would be that this ghost branch will be on log the graph in a somewhat hanging leaf. But it is not present. Any explanations as to why this happens is appreciated. Or maybe I am missing out on a flag to show hidden branches...

Comment: `Problem is: one cannot remember this hash forever.` I suspect that's not the only problem. Have you checked to see that this commit survives `git-gc`? I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't. Committing to a detached head is not part of any sane git workflow, but nobody ever said git wouldn't help you shoot yourself in the foot...

Comment: @grossvogel shockingly, the ghost commit survived a `git gc`. I don't think the garbage collection deletes unreferenced branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root reason that this "ghost" branch does not appear in your git log --all is that this log will only represent all branches, not all existing commits.
You have to consider that when you rebase commits you do not delete the old commits you just copy them to another parent, so they also are commit without any branch, like your ghost branch.

commits are like objects referenced by other objects, the only objects kept by git are the one referenced by branches. It is really like a garbage collected memory, your commit is an object you created in memory without referencing it. If you run `git gc` git will delete all these commit not referenced by any branch, including your "ghost branch".

The solution for you is to keep a reference to this commit, either by creating a branch as explained by wasworld, or by tagging your commit `git tag tagname sha1`.

EDIT: `git gc` will not delete recent commits, according to its manual page:

```
The optional configuration variable gc.reflogExpire can be set to indicate how long 
historical entries within each branch's reflog should remain available in this 
repository. The setting is expressed as a length of time, for example 90 days or 3
months. It defaults to 90 days.
```

So your ghost branch will be safe from `git gc` (which can be started without you asking for) for 90 days by default.

Comment: Are you sure `gc` will delete it even if it's still reachable from the reflog?

Answer (score 2):

The "ghost" branch, as you call it, is not a branch.  It's commits on the DAG which are not pointed to by anything.

Although I haven't looked at the code, I would imagine git log draws the graph and lists the commits by starting at the branch pointers and working backwards.  Since your commits in a detached HEAD state have nothing pointing to them, there's no way for git log to "see" them.

To fix that, simply create a branch with `git branch branch_name <commit>`.  Then git log will have something that points to the last commit done in the detached HEAD state and will "find" those commits when displaying the log / drawing the graph.

Answer (score 1):

In git branches are just pointers to commits. So when you say "Problem is: one cannot remember this hash forever" why not just create a branch at it?

```
git branch branch_name <commit>
```

What also is to keep in mind is that if you don't create any branch that points to this commit it will be gc'ed once the expiration time passed by. The default is 90 days.